# How to make an alias for a class that has a lot of generics (typescript)?

Tags: typescript, generics, socket.io, type-alias

I am utilizing the socket.io library for typescript. Whenever referencing a `Socket` or `Server` type in the code, four generic parameters are expected.  See [the docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/typescript/) for a full example, but the relevant part is this:

```
const io = new Server<
  ClientToServerEvents,
  ServerToClientEvents,
  InterServerEvents,
  SocketData
>();
```

And similarly with sockets.

My question is, how do I alias this long type? And, is it even possible? I have tried the following:

- `type` keyword:

```
export type DWFServer = Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents, InterServerEvents, SocketData>
```

- `interface` keyword:

```
export interface DWFServer extends Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents, InterServerEvents, SocketData> {}
```

- `class` keyword:

```
export class DWFServer extends Server< ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents, InterServerEvents, SocketData > {}
```

In the case of the type and interface keyword, I get the following compile error:

```
TS2693: 'DWFServer' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

In the case of the class keyword, I got no compilation failure, but a runtime error instantiating the aliased class:

```
TypeError: Class constructor Server cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Its also worth noting that the type alias is in another package, and I am directly exporting these types in that package's index.ts file.

Does anyone know how I can make this alias work?

Comment: Make a helper function. `export function createServer() { return new Server<ClientToServerEvents,
  ServerToClientEvents,
  InterServerEvents, SocketData>(); }`

Comment: That's a good way to solve the `Server` part, but I think I will still need a way to alias the `Socket` type because that is used in method signatures.

Comment: I don't see why, can you provide an example?